# How to get commits since a commit in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I'm frequently reviewing our commits since we last merged our dev branch to default (ie, we released a version) and so I want to list the commits since that merge in mercurial. Right now, I am using the date and am using log + grep and a date.
ex:

```
hg log -r "date('>2017-03-02')"
```

Is there a way to do this from a commit? Or should I just keep grabbing the date/datetime off the commit for the merge to default and doing what I'm doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All revisions in a branch starting with changeset XXX:

```
hg log -rXXX::
```

All revision in the whole repo starting with changeset XXX:

```
hg log -rXXX:
```

It's even mentioned on the first page of `hg help revsets`:

```
- Changesets between tags 1.3 and 1.5 mentioning "bug" that affect
  "hgext/*":

    hg log -r "1.3::1.5 and keyword(bug) and file('hgext/*')"
```